# AWS Lambda Node.js Runtime.ExitError during INIT phase

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

First off, I've made sure I have enough Lambda RAM and have increased timeouts.

I'm experiencing the following error for a very easy snippet of code.  Banging my head on why this is happening.

Lambda Response is:
{
"errorType": "Runtime.ExitError",
"errorMessage": "RequestId: 6277c632-0eaa-4aac-9c10-085c9850188e Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason"
}

CloudWatch Logs indicate:
2024-02-08T20:18:32.271-05:00   INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 579.46 ms Phase: init Status: error Error Type: Runtime.ExitError

I'm thinking this has an issue loading "@opentelemetry/api"..

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.  Here is my code.

```
const opentelemetry = require('@opentelemetry/api');
function myLog(msg) {
  const spanContext = opentelemetry.trace.getSpanContext(opentelemetry.context.active()) ?? opentelemetry.INVALID_SPAN_CONTEXT;
  console.log(`[!my my.trace_id=${spanContext.traceId},my.span_id=${spanContext.spanId}] - ${msg}`);
}
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  const msg = "Hello World";
  myLog(msg);
  process.nextTick(() => {
    callback(null, {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: msg
    });
  });
};
```

Lots and lots of iterations.

Comment: Did you package opentelemetry to the lambda bundle? Or to a layer? What happens if you remove the `require`?